# Strict aliasing and callbacks with user data

Tags: c++, strict-aliasing

I have a c++ library with a callback based C API. A callback type looks like this:

```
typedef struct {...} Result;
typedef void (*callback) (const Result* result, void* userData);
```

The user can register a callback like this, and can set a pointer to arbitrary data, and the library will pass that pointer back trough the callback.

My main concern here is:
Is it violate the strict aliasing rule or not? Do I need to change the type of the userData to char*?

Comment: Register the callback like how?

Comment: Why would this break the strict aliasing rule ? Do you encounter some compiler error ? What kind ? What compiler ?

Comment: @kebs: the absence of a compiler error isn't enough to establish the absence of a strict aliasing violation. The questioner has somewhat misunderstood the rules, is all, and fears that there may be an undiagnosed cause of UB in the code. Asking about it seems wise.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, I know the compiler can do disastrous  optimizations if we are not following the rules, but it wasn't clear what assumptions the compiler does. I had a silly thought it may tracks the pointers somehow, and I feared this chain will break with the void* cast... But now I think I understand how does it work.

Comment: @kebs: Actually I just wrote a little code (no callbacks involved) which breaks based on the existence of the -fno-strict-aliasing gcc flag, and it compiles without warning even with -Wall -Wstrict-aliasing=2 in any case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, aliasing only applies when pointers are indirected, not when they are passed as pointer values.  As long as the user behaves consistently you'll be fine.

That is, the user must ensure that if they pass `userData` of actual type `T`, then they always cast it to `T *` in the callback function before accessing it.

I'm assuming of course that you're not indirecting `userData` in your library, although again accessing it as a pointer (e.g. `printf("DEBUG: %p", userData)`) is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a more "C++"-ish interface for the C callback API, that might remove your aliasing concern.

```
struct Callback {
    void (*callback) (Callback *cb_this, const Result *result);
};
```

A C programmer using your C callback API to register a callback would do something like this:

```
struct MyCallback {
    struct Callback cb;
    int x;
    double y;
    /* ... */
};

void my_callback_func (Callback *cb_this, const Result *result) {
    MyCallback *my_cb = (MyCallback *)cb_this;
    /* ... */
}

MyCallback mycb = { { my_callback_func }, 0, 0, /* ... */ };
```

This way you don't have to worry about handling a `void *`. Instead, you are passed a single pointer to a `Callback`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: no question that this is bad for C++, but OP specifically said this was a C callback API being implemented in C++.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I clarified the answer, specifying this is for the C programmer using the callback API. Thanks and regards.

Comment: Ah, I understand now, thanks. For some reason I thought you were talking about C++ users of the C-like API.